# C: strtok overriding previous array values?

Tags: c, strtok

```
card * load_rolodex(FILE *read_file)
{
        int array_index = 0;
        char line [LINE_MAX];

        card *card_array = malloc(sizeof(card) * upper_bound);

        while (fgets(line, LINE_MAX, read_file)!= NULL)
        {
                card_array[array_index].last_name = strtok(line, " ");
                card_array[array_index].first_name = strtok(NULL, " ");
                card_array[array_index].phone_number = strtok(NULL, " ");
                size++;
                array_index++;
        }
        return card_array;
}
```

I am trying to save each token to values in a struct array.

I'm reading from a file with the following format

lastname firstname number
lastname firstname number
etc..

**My output is as follows:**

0 Pratt elyn 193)760-4405

1 Pratt Evelyn

2 Pratt velyn

3 Pratt velyn (193)760-4405

4 Pratt velyn 93)760-4405

5 Pratt  (193)760-4405

6 Pratt elyn 3)760-4405

etc...

**The output should be,**

0 Acosta Nadine (752)596-6540

1 Alford Skyler (635)736-7827

2 Allison Lawrence (475)886-5725

3 Alvarez Colin (659)911-6629

4 Ball Cadman (328)898-9532

5 Ballard Abel (853)190-0868

...

99 Pratt Evelyn (193)760-4405

As you can see, Pratt Evelyn (193)760-4405 is the last line of the file I am reading from,

I'm fairly new to C, and any explanation as to what is going wrong would be appreciated!

Comment: May we see the definition of `card`? The problem is that you are assigning pointers instead of copying the strings.

Comment: You have to use `strcpy()` to copy strings (and make sure there's enough space for the strings to be copied into); you can't simply assign pointers.  Or you could use `strdup()` to duplicate the string.  You should check that you don't get NULL back from `strtok()` because the input is incorrectly formatted, too.

Comment: Are these persons and number real? If so you should definitely remove them from here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to duplicate the strings you are saving. Like ...

```
card_array[array_index].last_name = strdup(strtok(line, " "));
card_array[array_index].first_name = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));
card_array[array_index].phone_number = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));
```

With your code, character array `line` is being re-used for all lines and its pointers are set into the `card_array` members. As you read new line, previous pointers will also get new data. Ultimately everyone will have characters from last line read.

Also, another problem with your code is you are returning local array - `line` which is wrong.

Comment: Remember that if you use `strdup()` to duplicate a string, you need to use `free()` when you are don.